# how can we differentiate the image filter effects?

Tags: java

How can we differentiate the image filter effects? on what basis we can check the image filters like based on color matrix or pixels?Actually iam developing the image filter library in java so i want to know the difference between each image filters. ex vintage effect, Polaroid effect,sepia effect..etc.

Try to help me.
Thaks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The article [*Image processing with Java 2D*](https://web.archive.org/web/20100126030254/http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-09-1998/jw-09-media.html) offers an accessible introduction to several common techniques, including [convolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution), [lookup tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lookup_table) and [thresholding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thresholding_%28image_processing%29).

Comment: Actually i want to know the basic difference between some of the filters like how can we differentiate each filter based on color matrix or rgb values. i have to develop some filters so that how can i proceed.

Comment: A complete discourse is beyond the scope of this forum, but I've added a few related links above.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean literal categorization of image filters, I find out this web link gives some good categories:

http://www.jhlabs.com/ip/filters/index.html